# Why I cannot find C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\javaw.exe?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

I actually don't know what to say because I try to search this file:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin\javaw.exe
```

and somehow it doesn't appear. How am I gonna fix this kinda problem?

Comment: We'll need more information. Why do you want to search this file? What happened? Are you using any mods? Are you troubleshooting something?

Answer (score 3):

Java is a program that other programs (like Minecraft) are built on. If you can't find that Java executable, chances are the problem is:

- You don't have any version of Java installed. You will need to [install Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/).
- You have a **different** version of Java installed. The folder `jre1.8.0_31` refers to Java version 8, update 31. Try going to `C:\Program Files\Java\`, or `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\` - do either of these locations exist, and is there another/different `jre` folder?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [Java](https://www.java.com/en/).

That is the default install directory, *if* you had actually installed Java, which you haven't.